# LM3914 4S lithium polymer meter

Tags: voltage, batteries, meter

I need help creating an LM3914 voltage meter (in bar mode). I looked at the datasheet and understand how to create a standard voltmeter (0-5V for example). However, what I need is an expanded range meter, and the datasheet seems a bit confusing about that.
To be precise, I need the circuit to meter a 4S lithium polymer battery. The voltage range has to be 12 - 16,8V.

I would appreciate any help,
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the engineering formula?
Basically what you do is take all the input values, add them together and than divide by the number of input values, should give you what you're looking for.

Comment: What is "the engineering formula" ?

Comment: That is basically the way to troll innocent engineers, like us. :/

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved it. I wanted a battery tester for a box with 4 D-size batteries. Not exactly your setup, but I do believe we have something in common.

All examples I have seen have a *separate* battery to drive the circuitry. That makes it easy for the voltage dividers at pin 4,6,7,8 since the external battery gives a "constant voltage" to compare to, and the tested battery goes "up and down" at pin 5.

But I wanted a self contained thing! And I believe you wanted that too.

So, following the image:

- Driven by 4 Size D batteries (to be tested).
- "Reference voltages" are created by using two LEDs. Voltage drop is fairly constant over a diode (i.e. LED) so if you measure voltage between V- and a point between resistor and LED, that voltage will follow your battery voltage minus 2V.
- Pin 4 is through LED to ground - that gives a lower reference at 2,2V. The LEDs go out at this level, ideally.  You should perhaps put a 11V zener diode here for your 4S.
- Pin 5 is connected to a voltage divider (LED and a resistor).
  Pin 5 will always be 2,2V below Voltage In. (Spec says "must be
  =1.5V below")
- Pin 6,7,8: "I winged it". Used the "engineering formulas" (1+(R1/R2)) as found
  here:
  https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/dotbar-display-driver-hookup-guide/all
  and modeled a little in Excel, used a 1k trimpot (=what I had) and it worked.

I noticed that the LED array goes "inside-out" (wrong lights) when I turn the trim pot knob the wrong way.

As a side effect, the two LEDs work as "ON"-indicators if voltage is too low for the LED array.

So for your 4S setup: The measured voltages on pin 4 and 5 should be lowered a fix amount by using a couple of diodes. Pin 4 should be.. what is an empty LIPO.. 11.0V?, minus atleast 1,5V = 9,0V. So that Pin 5, fed through a 2V diode as well, will have equal voltage as Pin 4 when battery is empty at 11V. And your trimpot should be set at 85% perhaps (corresponding to 14.4V-2V).

*But I still don't really know how this works.* By the way, what you were looking for is available on ebay, look for "lithium battery capacity indicator".

[image: LM3914 batt tester self powered]